# How do I get a class back after removing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a dropdown menu with an arrow on the right side that should go down when you click on it. But it doesn't turn back when you click on the menu again. You can see the example in the picture below:

When you don't click anything:

https://i.gyazo.com/b7cec5471aa9beff1611421e3ff36747.png

When you click anything:

https://i.gyazo.com/5744d2459c19d2f9a490a5fe337b4ec8.png

When you click on the same item (arrow doesn't move back)

https://i.gyazo.com/b324f91d673e8ad98645f9be95298a30.png

My Jquery code:

```
// menu toggle
    jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav").on(
        "click",
        ".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle",
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").each(
                function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").siblings("ul").slideUp(300);
                    $(this).children(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open").removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open");
                }
            );

            jQuery(this).toggleClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open");

            if(jQuery(this).hasClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open")) {
                jQuery(this)
                      .parent("a")
                      .addClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open")
                      .siblings("ul")
                      .slideDown(300);

                  } else {
                    jQuery(this)
                      .parent("a")
                      .removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open")
                      .siblings("ul")
                      .slideUp(300);
                  }
        }
    );
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="advanced-sidebar-nav advanced-sidebar-nav-default"><ul id="menu-sidebar-menu" class="advanced-sidebar-menu"><li id="menu-item-4701" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4701"><a href="#">Laptops<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4696" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4696"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i3/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4697" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4697"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i5</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4698" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4698"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i7/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i7</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4695" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4695"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/game-laptops/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Game laptops</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4703" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4703"><a href="#">Computers<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4709" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4709"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/tower/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Tower</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4710" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4710"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/workstation/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Workstation</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4708" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4708"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/game-computers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Game computers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4704" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4704"><a href="#">Monitoren<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4712" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4712"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/19/" style="padding-left:40px !important">19″</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4713" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4713"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/22/" style="padding-left:40px !important">22″</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4714" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4714"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/24/" style="padding-left:40px !important">24″</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4715" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4715"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/27/" style="padding-left:40px !important">27″</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4716" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4716"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/32/" style="padding-left:40px !important">32″</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4705" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4705"><a href="#">Netwerkapparatuur<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4721"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/switchers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Switchers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4718" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4718"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/nas/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Nas</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4722"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/thin-clients/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Thin clients</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4717" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4717"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/accespoints/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Access Points</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4719" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4719"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/repeaters/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Repeaters</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4720" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4720"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/routers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Routers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4706" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4706"><a href="#">Hard Drive<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4725" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4725"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-drive/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD Drive</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4726" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4726"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-m-2/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD M.2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4727"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-msata/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD Msata</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4723" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4723"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/sata-2-5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Sata 2.5″</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4724" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4724"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/sata-3-5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Sata 3.5″</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4707" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4707"><a href="#">Accessoires<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4729" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4729"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/kabels/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Kabels</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4728"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/adapters/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Adapters</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4730"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/memory/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Memory</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: It's difficult to identify the problem without looking into your html code. Can you please include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you each click removing all `-open` classes, and then immediately add it to the current element. So, next time will be the same - remove + add, so it will be adding the `-open` class each click. To fix this, you should not remove `-open` class for the active element with something like this:

```
        const self = this;

        jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").each(
            function() {
                $(this).removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").siblings("ul").slideUp(300);
                $(this).children(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open").not(self).removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open");
            }
        );
```

Comment: That was indeed the fix, thank you for helping me out. Props!